# Check if user shares with Twitter

Tags: objective-c, twitter, share, sharing

I am using an UIActivityViewController to show my share-dialogue.

How can I check if the user is using Twitter/Facebook/etc.?

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [activityViewController popoverPresentationController];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I want to customize the Text for sharing with different services, so this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`setCompletionWithItemsHandler`** like this:

**UPDATE** - remove the `if(complete)`

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError)
{
     //if (completed)
     //{
         if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
           //code for email
         } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
           //code for iMessage
         } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
           //code for Facebook
         } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
           //code for twitter
         }
     //}
 }];

UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [activityViewController popoverPresentationController];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I used your code, but it still doesn't work. Maybe you can take a look at my later post. Thank you!

Comment: I deleted the if-statement but it still does not change my text. What else could it be?

Comment: I tried to debug the code. It seems the compiler does not even step into the setCompletionWithItemsHanlder-Block.